# how to store data from json in sql table (python)

Tags: python, mysql, json

i have data in json file

for exmale:

```
{
"A": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
],
"B": [
    "d",
    "e",
    "f"
],
"C": [
    "g",
    "h",
    "i"
]
}
```

and for each key (A,B,C) in the json file i have table (sql table)

how can i go over my json file and store the data in the tables

using python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did not try because I do not know how to approach it
If you have a link or explanation on how to do it
It will really help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, it will head you on the right path.  Essentially you need to:

- iterate over the dictionary keys
- iterate over the list values in each key
- generate an SQL statement to insert in the table key, the value in the list

Basic example which uses the [items()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp) method to iterate over the key, value pairs in your dictionary.  You can then use a further loop to iterate over the values in the list and then generate your [SQL insert](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) line from it.  I just created a simple print statement to show what it could look like.

```
my_dict = {
    "A": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ],
    "B": [
        "d",
        "e",
        "f"
    ],
    "C": [
        "g",
        "h",
        "i"
        ]
}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for row in value:
        print(f"'INSERT INTO {key} (whateverColumn) VALUES {row}'")

'INSERT INTO A (whateverColumn) VALUES a'
'INSERT INTO A (whateverColumn) VALUES b'
'INSERT INTO A (whateverColumn) VALUES c'
'INSERT INTO B (whateverColumn) VALUES d'
'INSERT INTO B (whateverColumn) VALUES e'
'INSERT INTO B (whateverColumn) VALUES f'
'INSERT INTO C (whateverColumn) VALUES g'
'INSERT INTO C (whateverColumn) VALUES h'
'INSERT INTO C (whateverColumn) VALUES i'
```

I'd suggest reading through the two links I've included and playing around yourself.  There is a fair bit missing from your question like what's the column required in each of the tables, why are there separate tables etc.  It may be there is a better way of achieving the goal.  For instance, if you need to store JSON why not use a JSONB column in a Postgres database.